# How to prevent transitive dev dependency from being shrinkwrapped

Tags: node.js, npm, cucumberjs, npm-shrinkwrap

I have a package.json with cucumber listed as a devDependency. cucumber has a dependency on cucumber-html. For some reason when I run npm-shrinkwrap on my project, cucumber-html is included in the npm-shrinkwrap.json. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

package.json

```js
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "*",
    "bluebird": "2.2.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "compression": "*",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "etag": "*",
    "express": "~4.12.2",
    "interpolate": "*",
    "jade": "~1.9.2",
    "jwt-simple": "*",
    "lockdown": "0.0.6",
    "lodash": "*",
    "moment": "*",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "nano": "*",
    "node-rest-client": "*",
    "node-uuid": "*",
    "nodemailer": "*",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-jwt": "thedewpoint/passport-jwt",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "q": "*",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0",
    "validator": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "add-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.7.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
    "gulp-image-optimization": "^0.1.3",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-useref": "^1.3.0",
    "cucumber": "^0.5.2"
  }
```

npm-shrinkwrap.json

```js
 "cucumber-html": {
      "version": "0.2.3",
      "from": "cucumber-html@0.2.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cucumber-html/-/cucumber-html-0.2.3.tgz"
    },
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there a chance the cucumber-html module was installed by hand using `npm install cucumber-html` before shrinkwrap?

Comment: I don't think so. I deleted all of my node modules and did npm install and then npm shrinkwrap and I see it still

Comment: This could a version-specific bug. Have you checked the issue tracker for npm to see if someone else is facing a similar issue? Also, when you deleted node_modules, did you also delete your existing shrinkwrap file?

Comment: I checked npm and didnt see anyone with a similar issue. And yes I deleted the existing shrinkwrap before deleting as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand why everyone thinks this is an issue. This is the point behind npm-shrinkwrap. It says in the documentation that it **recursively** locks down each dependency. So the fact that it locks down a transitive dependency is expected behavior. To answer the original question, the docs don't indicate that this is possible, except by doing everything yourself by installing your dependencies into source control.